# __gc * to new manage c++ syntax

Tags: c++, visual-c++, clr

I'm porting a set old managed c++ code, to the new syntax. I found there is a code line like this.

`bool __gc * bValue`

I'm not sure what it does and how to convert it to new syntax.
This is what I tried but seems it not correct.

`bool ref ^ bValue`

Anyone there to help?

Comment: That was bad code, converting it doesn't make it good code.  Value types like `bool` should never be turned into reference types.

Answer (score 0):

In the first code snippet the `__gc` pointer is a managed pointer to a boolean value in the CLR heap.

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa712849(v=vs.71).aspx):

> Since regular C++ pointers are impossible in general to track precisely, __gc pointers are introduced. They are the pointers whose variables are known to the common language runtime garbage collector. The rules for casting __gc pointers are much stricter than those of standard C++ pointers

In C++/CLI `ref` keyword can be only used to declare managed classes or structs. So you should remove `ref` keyword from the second code snippet. And only `^` remains because it's a managed pointer.

```
bool^ bValue;
```